# Show that $2^a|(x-1)$ iff $2^a|(y-1)$.

Tags: number-theory

Suppose that $2^n + 1 =xy$, where $x$ and $y$ are integers > $1$ and $n>0$.
Show that $2^a|(x-1)$ iff $2^a|(y-1)$.
Here $a|b$ implies $a$ divides $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x-1)(y-1) = 1 + xy - x - y = 2^n - (x - 1) - (y - 1)$$

Then if $2^a$ divides $(x-1)$ then it definetile divides $(y-1)$, because

$$(y - 1) = 2^n - (x - 1) - (x-1)(y-1).$$

Answer (score 0):

WLOG let $x-1=p2^a,y-1=q2^b$ where $p,q$ are odd and $a\ge b>0$

$$1+2^n=xy=(p2^a+1)(q2^b+1)=pq2^{a+b}+p2^a+q2^b+1$$

$$q=2^{n-b}-pq2^a-p2^{a-b}$$

As $n-b>0$

$q$ will be even if $a>b$

and $q$ will remain odd if $a=b$